# add and substract months using simple math

Tags: math

im looking for mathematical formulas to add and subtract months to/from a date. i only need to know the year and month, therefor days can be ignored.

this is the adding months pseudo code i came up with:

```
OldYear = 2012 // current year
OldMonth = 3 // current month
AddMonths = 0 // the months to be added

FooBar = OldMonth + AddMonths

NewYear = OldYear + FooBar / 12
NewMonth = FooBar % 12

IF NewMonth = 0
    NewYear = NewYear - 1
    NewMonth = 12
END IF

// set AddMonths to 0 and the result will be 2012.03
// set AddMonths to 6 and the result will be 2012.09
// set AddMonths to 9 and the result will be 2012.12
// set AddMonths to 11 and the result will be 2013.02
// set AddMonths to 23 and the result will be 2014.02
// set AddMonths to 38 and the result will be 2015.05
```

and it works really great, but is there an even better way? i dont really like the need for the IF NewMonth = 0 readjustments.

but my actual problem is, that i couldnt come up with a counterpart formula to substract months. i tried various things, but everything failed and its driving me insane. so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a combination of my comment in @Matt's answer, and answer of @Matt

The formula can be greatly reduced if you adopt a 0-based month scheme.

pseudocode:

```
year = 2012;  // year 2012
month = 6;    // July (NOT June)
monthToAdd = -20;  // +ve/-ve means add/subtract

resultYear = (year * 12 + month + monthToAdd) /12;
resultMonth = (year * 12 + month + monthToAdd) mod 12;

// resultYear == 2010
// resultMonth == 10  , which means November
```

---

Edit: The original answer above assumed a zero-based month scheme, which seem being overlooked by some people.  To avoid confusion, we can of course use more intuitive 1-based month scheme, and do the 0-base conversion during calculation (though it make the calculation slightly messier):

```
year = 2012;  // year 2012
month = 7;    // July
monthToAdd = -20;  // +ve/-ve means add/subtract

resultYear = (year * 12 + (month - 1) + monthToAdd) /12;
resultMonth = ((year * 12 + (month - 1) + monthToAdd) mod 12) + 1

// resultYear == 2010
// resultMonth == 11  , which means November
```

Comment: wow i would have never come up with that solution. thank you both so much! :)

Comment: this does not work for use cases month=3 and monthToAdd=-3

Comment: @grepit why? Have a try: year = 2020, month = 3, monthToAdd=-3, the result is resultYear = 2020, resultMonth = 0, which means January 2020.  Please pay attention to the main point of this approach: we are using 0-based month scheme

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to multiply `OldYear` by 12 (thus converting it to months), adding or subtracting `AddMonths` or `SubMonths`, respectively, and then converting back to `NewYear` and `NewMonth` by using integer and modular division (depending on your programming language, you may be able to simplify this).

Comment: One more thing will help in simplifying the formula is to adopt a zero-based month presentation. i.e. 0 = January, 1 = Feb, and so on.  Of course you may want to convert from 1-based month presentation when you are getting input or performing output.

Comment: @AdrianShum, are you referring to `OldMonth` and `NewMonth` or `[Add/Sub]Month`?

Comment: Old/New month.  Just added an answer, please see it for reference

Answer (score -1):

Full credit to Adrian Shum for building the main logic but I think there is a edge case which the code is not 100% accurate for cases where we go back the same number of months as the month we are in. For example, if we are in March and we go back 3 months we should end up at Dec (Feb, Jan and Dec) .

here is the modified version:

```
year = 2020;  
month = 4;    
monthToAdd = -1; 
resultYear = (year * 12 + month + monthToAdd) /12;
resultMonth = (year * 12 + month + monthToAdd) % 12;

if month+monthToAdd == 0:
    resultMonth=12

elif (abs(monthToAdd)%month)==0:
    resultMonth=month

print(resultMonth)
print(resultYear)
```

Comment: No there is no such edge case: I have emphasised in my answer, that I am using 0-based month scheme.  Therefore, if you have 3 as month, it means April.  Subtracting 3 months from it will give you result month = 0 which means January.

Comment: and, your "fix" is basically flawed if you want to do 1-based month scheme.  Try using your logic to add 1 months to 2020-Nov (year = 2020, month = 11), it is giving weird result of 2021-Dec.  Not to mention your strange logic of `(abs(monthToAdd)%month)==0`, if you add 4 months (monthToAdd = 4) to Feb (month = 2), you are giving result month =  2